# voice recording from IPhone Chrome using HTML5 and javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, html, google-chrome

I am working on a english learning website. One part of our service are voice recording and grading. We use getUserMedia API to get users voice, and it works fine on PC browsers and iOS safari, however, it couldn't work on iOS Chrome.
  In [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/stream) compatible table, there is no iOS chrome item so I'm not sure is it possible to use this API on iOS chrome. Is there any other methods or APIs to get users voice on iOS chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you're probably out of luck. iOS keeps very strict limitations on what alternative browsers can do. This means that other iOS browsers like Chrome, Opera, etc. don't have access to many of the native features that Safari has.